LightningChart JS syncing 2 charts axis with mouse scroll, user trying to zoom in, and making the axis same oriantations
I am trying to create a component that sync between 2 types of charts, the first is a heatmap the second is a bar chart / segments chart / rectangle charts, will end up with the one that works the best.
I must make them look like this:
so that the Y axis will be aligned with the same values on the same line
the same grid
same when the user zoom in they should stay together because this resembels the depth of the data.
In order to show the same data for the same depth aligned together for both charts

when I tried to do it this is the result which is not good


problem 1 the axis are not aligned because the lables oriantation are not the same
problem 3 the values of the axises are not aligned they suppose to have the same depth but they dont even after using the sync function of the axis.
For the right chart, the axises doesnt show the same nubmers as the left chart start from the same (0,0) point and I cant figure out how to fix this. the direction of the axis is bad because it grows towards down and not up like on the left chart.

I used this function to sync between the axises
    synchronizeAxisIntervals(axisPSD, axisRMS);

but it does not work properly,when the user want to scroll to zoom-in,it does not work.
code to regenerate in reactjs
createRMSGraph.ts
import React from 'react';
import { lc } from './lightningChartObject';
import { Axis, AxisScrollStrategies, ColorHEX, SolidFill, Themes } from '@arction/lcjs';

const createRMSGraph = (divRef: string): Axis => {
  const theme = Themes.light;
  const BackgroundFill = new SolidFill({
    color: ColorHEX('#ffffff'),
  });
  const chart = lc
    .ChartXY({
      container: divRef,
      theme: theme,
      defaultAxisY: {  opposite : true },
    })
    .setSeriesBackgroundFillStyle(BackgroundFill)
    .setTitle('');
  console.log(chart.getDefaultAxisX());
  chart.getDefaultAxisX().setTitle('X Axis');
  chart.getDefaultAxisY().setTitle('Y Axis');

  const segmentSeries = chart
    .addSegmentSeries()
    .setDefaultStyle((figure) => figure.setStrokeStyle((stroke) => stroke.setThickness(20)));

  const histogramData = [{ x: 25.01, y: 19.52317495 }];
  histogramData.forEach((point) => {
    segmentSeries.add({ startX: point.x, startY: 0, endX: point.x, endY: point.y });
  });

  return chart.getDefaultAxisX();
};

export { createRMSGraph };


createPSDGraph.ts
import React from 'react';
import { lc } from './lightningChartObject';
import { Axis, ColorHEX, SolidFill, Themes } from '@arction/lcjs';

const createPSDGraph = (divRef: string): Axis => {
  //init
  const theme = Themes.light;
  const BackgroundFill = new SolidFill({
    color: ColorHEX('#ffffff'),
  });
  const chart = lc
    .ChartXY({
      container: divRef,
      theme: theme,
    })
    .setSeriesBackgroundFillStyle(BackgroundFill)
    .setTitle('');

  chart.getDefaultAxisX().setTitle('X Axis');
  // chart.addAxisX({ type: 'logarithmic', base: 10 }).setTitle('X Axis');
  chart.getDefaultAxisY().setTitle('Y Axis');

  // add heatmap on top of
  chart.addHeatmapGridSeries({
    columns: 901,
    rows: 50,
  });
  return chart.getDefaultAxisY();
};

export { createPSDGraph };

MERGraphs.tsx
import { Box } from '@mui/system';
import React, { useEffect, useId, useState } from 'react';
import { createPSDGraph } from './utils/createPSDGraph';
import { createRMSGraph } from './utils/createRMSGraph';
import { synchronizeAxisIntervals } from '@arction/lcjs';

const MERGraphs = () => {
  const id = useId();
  useEffect(() => {
    const axisPSD = createPSDGraph(`${id}-PSD`);
    const axisRMS = createRMSGraph(`${id}-RMS`);
    synchronizeAxisIntervals(axisPSD, axisRMS);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', width: '1000px', height: '500px' }}>
      <Box id={`${id}-PSD`} sx={{ width: '100%' }}></Box>
      <Box id={`${id}-RMS`} sx={{ width: '100%' , rotate: "90deg" }}></Box>
    </Box>
  );
};

export { MERGraphs };


